# find -mtime option on linux listing all files regardless of time?

Tags: file, unix, find, xargs, datemodified

I'm trying to use the linux `find` command to show me the files in my current directory that have been modified in the last 24h. To test my command, I piped it to `ls` as below.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 | xargs -I{} ls -lh {}`

but this command displays all the files in my directory, some of which were modified last year. What am I missing here? I also tried -atime and -ctime options out of curiosity and got seemingly the same file list.

Many thanks for the advice!

Comment: If the directory has been modified, then one of the outputs of find is going to be `.`.  So `xargs` will call `ls -lh .`.  Maybe just add `-type f` to the find invocation.

Comment: Tried the -f. But still lists all the files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issues was caused because I had the wrong system time on my raspberry.
This was because systemd-timesyncd.service was no longer running.
After:

```
 sudo systemctl unmask systemd-timesyncd.service
 sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
 sudo reboot
```

the system time was correct again. Note that the pi needs to be connected to a network for this to work. And also, of course, past wrong file dates don't get fixed by this (duh).